# Youtube API: See which video id is currently playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

Is there a way to display/see/return which video (so, which videoID) is playing at the moment?

This is the basic code of the Iframe API:

```
var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'pJ18QeQy0e8',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
        'onError': onError,
      },
        playerVars: {

                    'controls': 0,
                    'showinfo': 0,
                    'iv_load_policy': 3,
                    'wmode': "opaque",
                },
    });
  }
```

after the first video has finished. This event will be called:

```
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
if(event.data === 0) {    
        player.stopVideo();
player.loadVideoById(getId());          

        }
  }
```

The getId() function will get another videoId to play..

I want to display in a DIV, which videoId is currently playing

Answer (score 20):

```
player.getVideoData()['video_id']
```

OR

```
var video_data = player.getVideoData()
video_data['video_id']
```

**Solution:**

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data === 0) {    
        player.stopVideo();
        player.loadVideoById(player.getVideoData()['video_id']);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work anymore trying to access this function returns `e.player.getVideoData is not a function`

Comment: is there any similar api function in Android?

Comment: @ThunderWiring, there is one that is deprecated. The document says that Google is using the same IFrame API for all: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 4):

You can use [getVideoUrl](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#getVideoUrl) to get the url and take the id part out of this url.

Comment: Assuming that the video url is correct (watch or embed urls), you can pull the video id like so: 

`var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;

var match = e.target.getVideoUrl().match(regExp);

var videoID = match[2];`

Answer (score 0):

Using window.location.href...

You can paste this into the console on desktop and if you're on a youtube video it'll take the id out of the url, not elegant at all but it works for desktop

```
var url = window.location.href;

var isYTvid = url.indexOf("www.youtube.com/watch?v=");
if (isYTvid != -1) {
    var id = url.slice(url.indexOf("=") + 1 , url.length);
    console.log(id);
}
```